# How do I stop Skype from popping up SecurityError: Error #2060: Security sandbox violation?

Tags: windows-8.1, skype, flash, flash-player

I'm getting this error constantly. I have to click Dismiss All several half-dozen times. I already uninstalled Flash and restarted Skype, but the problem still happens.

[image: Imgur]

```
SecurityError: Error #2060: Security sandbox violation: ExternalInterface caller https://z.moatads.com/swf/p6.v3.swf cannot access https://static.skypeassets.com/adserver/AdLoader.html?version=1.66.21.
    at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/_initJS()
    at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/call()
    at periscope/onStateChange()
    at periscope/init()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is obviously caused by several ad banners trying to do stupid things, you can just **forbid** all Skype banners to use Flash at all (which also protects you from potential security issues, so it's a win-win). Also considering it won't prevent ads, it will still get them some money for providing the infrastructure, so better than completely blocking.

- Open **Internet Settings** in **Control Panel**, through **Internet Explorer's Tools** menu, or simply run `inetcpl.cpl` from the Start Menu.
- Go to the **Security** tab.
- Select **Restricted Sites**.
- Click on the **Sites** button.
- Add `https://apps.skype.com`.
- Close both windows.
- Restart Skype

This will now prevent all ad banners in Skype to use Flash (or pretty much any other web technique), so should also keep the popup errors away.

Comment: But there is a different host name each time it pops up.

Comment: @Chloe Updated my answer with a different, probably better and easier approach.

Comment: Nice! It totally blocks advertisements!